# Impex to remove solr search configuration for website

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

What is the right impex to remove the value of `Solr Search Configuration`? The regular `INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;` does not include a field for `Solr Search Configuration`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];solrFacetSearchConfiguration
;electronics-uk;
```